# Setting an optional parameter explicitly when calling a PHP function

Tags: php, function, parameter-passing, optional-parameters

I defined the function `f` in PHP:

```
function f($r, $o1="1", $o2="2") { echo($r . $o1 . $o2 . "\n"); }
```

Now I can call `f` (1) without the optional parameters, (2) with the first or (3) with both optional parameters:

```
f(0);           // 012
f(0, "a");      // 0a2
f(0, "a", "b"); // 0ab
```

Is it also possible to call `f` only with the second parameter? e.g.

```
f(0, $o2="X");  // 01X
```

I'm using `5.5.12-2ubuntu4.1`.

Comment: Apparently, you can't. But you can pass arguments as an associative array.

Comment: PHP does only support positional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your function as this:

```
function f($r, $o1=null, $o2=null) {
  if(is_null($o1)) $o1 = "1";
  if(is_null($o2)) $o1 = "2";
  echo($r . $o1 . $o2 . "\n");
}
```

Now you know that you can always pass null to use default value, and you can later change the default values without changing the callers.

Answer (score 0):

You could make all parameters optional:

```
function f($r = null, $o1 = "1", $o2 = "2")
{
    $r = $r ? : 0;
    echo($r . $o1 . $o2 . "\n");
}
```

This gives you:

```
f(0);           // 012
f(null, "a");   // 0a2
f(1, "a");      // 1a2
```

Answer (score -1):

Since PHP 5.6, you can use "..." before a parameter to tell the interpreter that your function accepts a random number fo arguments.

Before PHP 5.6, you can pass an array instead of a list of params.
You can also use func-get-arg() or func-get-args() and check whether the second parameter is "disabled" (ie: == null)

Comment: Does this allow you to check that $b was passed instead of $a?